# Blender 2.82 - addon missing? - Export to After Effects JSX

Tags: add-on

looking for info about this addon: Export to After Effects JSX A tutorial 2.8 shows the addon in "Testing" don't find it in 2.82

Comment: Hi. If you need to add more information to your question you can use the [edit] link below it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official releases do not include the add-ons from the [Blender Add-ons Contrib](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons-contrib) repository. However you can download and install them yourself. The exporter for Adobe After Effects (.jsx) can be found [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons-contrib/src/branch/main/io_export_after_effects.py).

In order to install it:

1. Go [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons-contrib/src/branch/main/io_export_after_effects.py) and click *Download File*.
2. Open add-on preferences in Blender (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).
   [image: Preferences]
3. Click the install button and select the downloaded file.
   [image: Install add-on]
4. Enable the add-on.
   [image: Enable the add-on]

Comment: The links you provide only lead to Blender Developer Portal, is it right ? I can't find the exporter nowhere online...

Comment: @Pitoring Blender migrated from Phabricator to Gitea earlier this year, hence the link doesn't work anymore. You can find the repository here now: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons-contrib